# Can't type the whatever set as mapleader in vim?

Tags: vim

In my vimrc, when I set `let mapleader = ','` I can't type the comma in insert mode. When I set `` let mapleader = '`' ``, I can't type the backtick. And it's the same with any other key I've tried and with any file type except for .tex files.

Right now I have `` let mapleader = '`' `` in my vimrc, and no other settings on leader key anywhere else.

I use vimtex and I can compile .tex files using `\ll`, so the localeader key is the default `\`? Why did it not use the mapleader key `` ` ``? Also, I am able to type `` ` `` in insert mode only in .tex files, and this maybe related to the vimtex setting that uses backtick ` as the default leader key for insert mode mappings?

I use Ultisnips, and uses the current mapleader `` ` `` to select the snippets. I also use YouCompleteMe, which uses `<tab>` for selection.

So how can I type in vim the mapleader key `` ` `` in insert mode?

Below is my :imap output.

[image: imap]

Update:

The problem has to do with my Ultisnips setting in .vimrc.

Since I have YouCompleteMe, I can't do `let g:UltisnipsExpandTrigger='<tab>'`, so I changed it to `let g:UltisnipsExpandTrigger='<leader>'`, and this caused the problem where I can't type the leader key in insert mode. To make YCM and Ultisnips compatible, here is a solution I found that allows you to keep  for expanding snippets. See http://0x3f.org/blog/make-youcompleteme-ultisnips-compatible/!

Comment: Use `:let mapleader` to verify that the mapleader is actually set.

Comment: Yes I verified that, also with `:echo mapleader`

Comment: what does `:imap` return?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I added a screenshot of :imap at the end of my question, but I can't see the problem. Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: The `i  \`` thing looks like a problem.

Comment: I can't view the image right now, the site is blocked but the comment from melpomene should be related to your problem. If you want to know who set the mapping, you can run **:verbose imap `**

Comment: @melpomene @LievenKeersmaekers Thank you! I figured out the problem! I had `let g:UltisnipsExpandTrigger='<leader>' `, once I change it to ``let g:UltisnipsExpandTrigger='`'  ``,  I was able to type backtick in insert mode while having it as leader key.